# Why can't Python see environment variables?

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables

I'm working on Debian Jessie with Python 2. Why can't Python's `environ` see environment variables that are visible in bash?

```
# echo $SECRET_KEY
xxx-xxx-xxxx
# python
>>> from os import environ
>>> environ["SECRET_KEY"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/prescribing/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
```

I set these environment variables using `/etc/environment` - not sure if that's relevant:

```
SECRET_KEY=xxx-xxx-xxx
```

I had to run `source /etc/environment` to get bash to see them, which I thought was strange.

UPDATE: `printenv SECRET_KEY` produces nothing, so I guess `SECRET_KEY` is a shell not an environment variable.

Comment: That's not an environment variable; it is just a shell variable until you `export` it.

Comment: Really? I thought `/env/environment` was for setting environment variables - is this incorrect?

Comment: Using `source /env/environment` only sets variables in the shell, not environment variables accessible by child processes.

Comment: Yes, no, maybe — yes, it is incorrect (because they're only environment variables if you export them); no, it is correct that `/etc/environment` might be used to set environment variables (though it isn't a standard file, AFAIK, but it is referenced in Ubuntu, it seems); maybe, because it depends what you write in the file (or what is written in the file if you don't have control over its contents).

Comment: What OS is this on? I've never seen `/env/environment` used, not for shells at any rate.

Comment: Typo sorry, should have been `/etc/environment`. Fixed in question.

Comment: I was trying to follow https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fenvironment - I'm now confused about what I should be putting in that file. Should it be `foo=bar` or `export foo=bar`? I had `foo=bar` but perhaps that's incorrect.

Comment: Since the referenced file has a restriction ([Note: Variable expansion does not work in /etc/environment](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fenvironment)), it is not clear how that is processed.  It might be handled differently from normal files, somehow.  However, if you use `source /etc/environment` and it does not contain `export` directives, then they aren't environment variables and won't be exported by default.  Look up the [`set -k` and `set -a`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin) options.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to *export* environment variables for child processes to see them:

```sh
export SECRET_KEY
```

Demo:

```sh
$ SECRET_KEY='foobar'
$ bin/python -c "import os; print os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', 'Nonesuch')"
Nonesuch
$ export SECRET_KEY
$ bin/python -c "import os; print os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', 'Nonesuch')"
foobar
```

You can combine the setting and exporting in one step:

```sh
export SECRET_KEY=xxx-xxx-xxxx
```

Note that new variables in `/etc/environment` do not show up in your existing shells automatically, not until you have a *new login*. For a GUI desktop, you'll have to log out and log in again, for SSH sessions you'll have to create a new SSH login. Only then will you get a new tree of processes with the changes present. Using `source /etc/environment` only sets 'local' variables (the file is not a script). See [How to reload /etc/environment without rebooting?](https://superuser.com/questions/339617/how-to-reload-etc-environment-without-rebooting) over on Super User.

Comment: I was trying to follow the instructions in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fenvironment - should I use `export foo-bar` instead of `foo=bar` in /etc/environment?

Comment: It's worth noting that `os.environ` is only loaded the first time the `os` module is imported. So if you call a `subprocess` to execute a bash script, when it returns to the python script it won't be able to see the new environment variables that were possibly exported in your bash script.

Comment: @Richard: in your question you named it `/env/environment`, not `/etc/environment`.. I'm not *that* familiar with Ubuntu, I'll have a look as to how the OS is using those. Did you restart at all after making changes to the file?

Comment: @amza: a subprocess won't be able to set variables for the parent process *anyway*. This has nothing to do with `os.environ` being loaded when first imported (the mapping is actually built when *Python starts*). The process environment can only be altered by the current process or a *parent* process, and `subprocess` never creates such a process, so the distinction is entirely moot.

Comment: @Richard: a quick experiment shows that changes in `/etc/environment` only apply to *new logins*; after editing I didn't see the change in new subshells, but use `ssh localhost` and those new login sessions do see the new variable. So I suspect that this is used by PAM to set up the new user environment.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I exported it but still get the error.

Comment: @Ariel: that's not something that we can help you with, though. I can't see how you exported your shell variables, and what software is not seeing that variable set or how you run your software. Exported shell variables are visible to *child processes only*, not to processes started from a different shell or parent process, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it was an array variable and it turns out those cannot be exported at all. I was trying to read it from a Python shell, like the OP.