# Why is Python unable to retrieve value of an environment variable even though that variable has value when tested via bash?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I want to use a value from an environment variable. I have set it in the `~/.bashrc` file and I am able to see that in the new shells and in the current shell(obviously, after `source`ing it). However, when I import the same variable in Python3 shell(both in the existing and in the new shells), the value returned is always `None`.

I read a lot and found a [relatable answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993885/why-cant-python-see-environment-variables) but it did not solve my problem or rather, I could not understand it.

My bashrc file is:

```
SLACK_URL="https://hooks.slack.com/"
```

I am able to see the value in the terminal but not in the Python shell:

```
ubuntu@ip-A.B.C.D:~$ echo $SLACK_URL 
https://hooks.slack.com/
ubuntu@ip-A.B.C.D:~$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.getenv('SLACK_URL')
>>>
```

I expect to see the actual variable's value but instead I am getting `None`.

Comment: What's hard to understand about that answer? It literally says: use `export` when defining the env var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `export` the variable in your .bashrc file so other programs can see it:

```
export SLACK_URL="https://hooks.slack.com/"
```

For more about what `export` does, see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/58814/how-do-i-add-environment-variables

Comment: This is a common duplicate; by having answered it you have now made it that much harder for the OP to delete their question if they so wish, however.